# CSS center position:absolute background

Tags: html, css, css-position, center

I'm trying to keep the "sp" and "bg" divs centered at all times but I can't seem to do it. It is centered up until the width of the window exceeds the width of the image. After that, the image stays to the left of the page. All I want to change is that the image should move to the center of the page at all widths. Ideal answer would be with keeping position: absolute.

Thanks!

```
<div id="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider">
            <div class="bg"> <width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
            <div class="sp"> <img src="../imgs/01_done.png" width="100%" height=100%"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider-wrapper{display:none;height:100%;position:fixed;width:100%;z-index:1000000}
#slider {position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%}
#slider .bg {position:absolute; max-height: 100%; display: none;} 
#slider .sp {position:absolute;z-index:10000; max-height: 100%; display: none;}
```

Edit: cut down some of the code to make it simpler.

Comment: Can you give me a fiddle?

Comment: Any reason you couldn't use `background-image` and use `background-position` to center and `background-size: cover` to keep it full width?

Comment: Some of your HTML is invalid.  `<width="100%" height="100%"/>` is not considered valid code.  What is this trying to accomplish? Also, `z-index="10000"` should instead be `style="z-index:10000"`

Comment: As @ShayR mentioned below in his answer, apply the margin-left and margin-right auto to your slider-wrapper css. That should center that container on the screen left and right regardless of the screen size. As far as the img with 100% width and height, unless you don't care about the aspect ration of the images, you should use the 100% only in one direction (width or height). You would probably want to use pre-sized images for best results.

Comment: You might want to use the text-align center and vertical-align as well in the css for the slider-wrapper to position your slider div at it's center as well. That's as far as I want to comment, considering that it will ultimately be affected by javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Simple as this:

```
.bg, .sp {margin: 0 auto; width: n px;}
```

Comment: Using this, the image width would always be 100% of the screen, which is not desired. When the window width exceeds the image width, I simply want the image to be in the center of the window, without being as wide as the window. Right now, all of the desired points already exist, except the fact that when the window width exceeds the image width, the image stays on the left side of the page, and doesn't move to the center. Hope that makes sense... Thanks!

Comment: please provide a fiddle. just set the `width` to the width of your images.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to centre an element from css, you could use the `margin` clause:

```
#centred
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width:100px;
}
```

As for the background, if you want a background for the element, you could also use the above code for it, and define the `height` property as well.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS

First of all, Clean up the CSS and get rid of the absolute positioning it becomes a real pain later in development. <--unless absolutely necessary

Clean up HTML remove the  containers why do you have these?
You dont need to restate 100% if its in the CSS. Also the issue with %'s is they need a reference like 1000px to know what to scale relatively to.

```
CSS

#slider-wrapper{
clear:both;
position: relative;
max-width: 1000px;
width: 100%;
}

#slider{
    position: relative;
    width:100%
    height:100%
    }

    .sp,
    .bg {
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work since it makes the images have the width of the screen at all times. As I mentioned in an earlier comment:
Using this, the image width would always be 100% of the screen, which is not desired. When the window width exceeds the image width, I simply want the image to be in the center of the window, without being as wide as the window. Right now, all of the desired points already exist, except the fact that when the window width exceeds the image width, the image stays on the left side of the page, and doesn't move to the center. Hope that makes sense... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:
http://jsfiddle.net/sHnmx/

```
.bg, .sp {margin: 0 auto; width: 10%;}
```

And give width of image in css in pixels(In place of width, give width of your image).